Regex extract query string parameter value, potentially URL encoded
I have URLs like so, with query with a parameter called "myParamName" (case INsensitive) which should have a numeric value.  For example:
https://website.com/something?myParamName=123&a=b
This URL itself is passed to another page as an actual query string parameter itself called "goto".  The URL must be encoded to be handled correctly by anothersite.com
https://anothersite.com?goto=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Fsomething%3FmyParamName%3D123%26a%3Db
So my input value for the regex match is:
goto=https%3A%2F%2Fwebsite.com%2Fsomething%3FmyParamName%3D123%26a%3Db
Notice the myParamName%3D123 rather than myParamName=123.  So what I need to do is extract a numeric value which immediately follows either = or %3d or %3D
What I've tried gets me the = or the %3D, but not the numeric value after it
(?i)myParamName(=|%3d)[^&]
Can someone give me a little help here, how to extract that numeric value after = or %3d?
Regex101.com example:
https://regex101.com/r/hResKm/1

Which language/libs do you use? Better Uri-unescape/escape.

You may use (?i)myParamName(?:=|%3d)(\d+)

@GillesQuénot PySpark SQL, so I'm guessing just Python in terms of the engine

@anubhava that doesn't seem to work, doesn't match anything.  I'm trying to extract a value, and I think ?: can't work for that?

It works in python demo: https://regex101.com/r/hResKm/2

Do you have to do this with a regexp? Why not use urllib?

myParamName(?:=|%3[dD])(\d+) will do then. myParamNamecan also be written as [mM][yY]... and so on.

Try this:
(?i)myParamName(?:=|%3d|%3D)([^&][0-9]+)

Worked in regex101 and on python:
import re

tests = """myParamName123
myParamName&a
myParamName&123
myParamName=asdf
myParamName=999+123
myPaRAMName=123
myParamName%3d456""".split('\n')

pattern = r"(?i)myParamName(?:=|%3d|%3D)([^&][\d]+)"

for test in tests:
    print(test, '-->', re.findall(pattern, test))

Output:
myParamName123 --> []
myParamName&a --> []
myParamName&123 --> []
myParamName=asdf --> []
myParamName=999+123 --> ['999']
myPaRAMName=123 --> ['123']
myParamName%3d456 --> ['456']

